# Firebase response time is very slow. How do I improve response time speed?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase to retrieve data and display it on a webpage. It nearly takes 4 to 5 secs to get response even if there is single record.

Code:

```
firebase.database().ref('categories').on('child_added',function(snapshot){
    console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

I even tried with value event, but there is no difference.

```
firebase.database().ref('categories').on('value',function(snapshot){
    console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Comment: I think firebase has its hardware in the us, where are you from? I can't think of anything else. Still, 5 seconds is way too much. Maybe they're having some kind of trouble?

Comment: I think they are indeed experiencing some kind of issue right now because my integration with Firebase Database is also going very, very slow at the moment. The same code a couple of weeks ago was performing very fast.

Comment: Hi @JonasGrumann I am from India and I have also selected app engine location India.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Must be that firebase is having problem in the whole. Previously, it was working fine, time to shift from firebase sighhh :/

Comment: When I´m on a VPN and try to connect to Firebase using Android Emulator, the authentication takes from 7 to 10 min. When I turn off the VPN client on my computer, the response time is satisfactory.

Comment: Can you contact their support and post their final response here?

Comment: I don't understand the firebase location-dependent speed  issue. I thought the benefit of using firebase is that you have the power of a distributed database, ready for world-scaling. Very slow for me, in Australia.

Comment: Do you have any information about the response time problem?